# Journal “TIME” in this week

Tags: idioms, prepositions, questions, time

I have a simple question of the title in the cover page for TIME this week. It is described that “we are not frayed at the edges - we are ripped at the damn seams”. This is one of the sentence of special topic regarding the inside the new American way of war, but I did not understand what this sentence stands for. I guess this is a kind of euphemism, but does anybody explain about this?

Here is a link to the journal;
http://time.com/5042700/inside-new-american-way-of-war/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a euphemism, it's a metaphor.  Clothing worn for a long time gets frayed at the edges.  If it's under even greater stress, it may get "ripped at the seams," e.g., torn apart.

Answer (score 1):

If you say that something is fraying at the edges, it means that is gradually disintegrating – referring to cloth material or fabric.

The metaphor is then extended to be more dramatic

Ripped at the seams means that something is falling apart totally, as clothing would if it were torn at the seams. Seam: A line where two pieces of fabric are sewn together in a garment or other article.